# ChangeToken color of NSTokenfield

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, appkit

I would like to style the token of the NSTokenfield, is there any way to do that? The minimum I would like to change is the token colour.

Comment: See [NSTokenField: different colors for tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17672413/nstokenfield-different-colors-for-tokens) and [Custom-drawn tokens in NSTokenField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861070/custom-drawn-tokens-in-nstokenfield).

Comment: Thanks for this. Has anyone else worked on this?